# The key not valid for use in specified state while using -pri

Tags: encryption, key, rsa, password-encryption

I am following this link to encrypt/decrypt passwords:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/yxw286t2(v=vs.100)

I was able to encrypt passwords in web.config on the **Remote Server**. I can decrypt. I was able to create the RSA Key container and export it.

I am not able to create keys using the -pri tag:
aspnet_regiis -px "SampleKeys" keys.xml -pri

It will only generate keys.xml for me if I take out the -pri. I get the error "The key not valid for use in specified state."

I did create the RSA container using the following:
Create Keys

1. From the (run as administrator) console prompt, change directory to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
2. Execute the command to create the keys: aspnet_regiis -pc "ConnectionKeys" –exp
3. Execute the command to export the keys:
4. From the (run as administrator) console prompt, execute the following command line to grant permissions:   aspnet_regiis -pa "ConnectionKeys" "IIS_IUSRS"

I am able to encrypt/decrypt on the remote server.
However, I need to be able to export the keys and have the rest of the developers on my team use them. I first tried testing on my local machine.

If I create keys from my machine, I am able to encrypt/decrypt.
If I copy web.config from the Remote Server to my machine and export/import the keys.xml, I get the following error:
"The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 128 bytes"